# How can I switch the bandwidth of my PCIE 3?

Tags: pci-express, acer

I've been tinkering around looking for ways to downgrade the PCIE 3 bandwidth allocated for my Nvidia GPU from x4 to x2. My reason is I like to allocate x4 to my NVME SSD. I tried looking at BIOS, but none.

1. To see if I am able to maximize the advertized read speed of Samsung 970 EVO Plus or close to that. Currently, I am only hitting around 1400 MBps sequential read. EVO Plus advertized read speed is 3500MBps.
2. I am not a hardcore gamer (just DOTA2 basically hehe) and often I use my laptop for coding/work instead of games. So, I'd benefit more on the SSD's optimized speed instead of the GPU.

[image]

My laptop is: ACER Aspire E5-576G-82RZ

Will removing the GPU automatically switch the bandwidth? And if I put it back will it revert? Found an unconfirmed answer here: [Change by software the PCIe bandwidth from 16x to 8x](https://superuser.com/questions/1525404/change-by-software-the-pcie-bandwidth-from-16x-to-8x)

Comment: It depends entirely on where/how the PCIe lanes come from. On desktop machines the GPU PCIe lanes are directly wired to the CPU, while the "other" devices are wired to another device called the Platform Controller Hub which in turn connects to the CPU. you cannot "merge" different sources of PCIe lane and even if all your lanes came from the same place not all hardware is configurable via software. Many PCIe switches are simply "dumb" devices that are configured in hardware and once set up by the manufacturer nothing else can be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put that's not possible.

Even if you could strip away PCIe lanes from the GPU, those lanes wouldn't magically reappear on the NVMe interface.

If there's no BIOS option (which is unlikely) the lanes are just hardwired and there's no way to change anything.